# Как писать юнит тесты?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Мне надо написать несколько unit tests на код ниже, проверить output. Может кто подскажет где искать или хотябы один пример?

```
Prime factors of 4 are: 2 x 2
Prime factors of 7 are: 7
Prime factors of 30 are: 2 x 3 x 5
Prime factors of 40 are: 2 x 2 x 2 x 5
Prime factors of 50 are: 2 x 5 x 5
```

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a  number greater than 1 : ");

        int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int num = input;
        int i = 1;
        string primeString = "";
        while (++i <= num)
        {

            while (num % i == 0)
            {
                primeString += " " + i;
                num /= i;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The prime factors of " + input + " are:" + primeString);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to check another number");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Вы не можете написать юнит тест на этот код, пока он работает с консолью. Вынесете работу с консолью в отдельный класс / интерфейс и замокайте его.

Comment: там вроде надо открыть тест файл и добавить депенденси. Так учитель обьяснил.Может вы знаете что добавить в эту строку ,чтобы между цыфрами был знак умножения Console.WriteLine("The prime factors of " + input + " are:" + primeString); factors of 4 2*2

Comment: Вынесите логику калькулятора в отдельный класс и тестируйте именно этот класс. А для unit-тестов вам понадобится отдельный проект, к которому будут подключен фреймворк для тестирования (например, NUnit, XUnit, MSTest).

Answer (score 2):

На ваш код не напишешь тесты, у вас должен быть выделен отдельно класс калькулятора в проекте.

Обычно выделяют отдельный проект под бизнес-логику, отдельный проект под инфраструктуру, поэтому я расположу калькулятор в отдельный проект, а не в ConsoleApp1.

Хотя бы так, без выделения интерфейса:

```
using System;

namespace Logic
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int Factorial(int num)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

И в отдельном классе (обычно делают в отдельном проекте, я сделаю отдельный проект Logic.Tests) нужны тесты именно на калькулятор:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Logic.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for <see cref="Calculator"/>
    /// </summary>
    public class CalculatorTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test01()
        {
            // Arrange
            var calculator = new Calculator();
            var input      = 5;
            var expected   = 120;

            // Act
            var result = calculator.Factorial(input);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }
    }
}
```

И приложение будет иметь примерно такой вид (убрал для наглядности отлов FormatException):

```
using System;
using Logic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var calculator = new Calculator();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            var input  = EnterNumber();
            var result = calculator.Factorial(input);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result for {input} is {result}");
        }

        private static int EnterNumber()
        {
            string input  = Console.ReadLine();
            int    parsed = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            return parsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Итого, вот так вышло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Проект ConsoleApp1 зависит от Logic, а проект Logic.Tests зависит от Logic, не забудьте подключить проекты в dependencies)

В проекте с тестами не забудьте подключить нужные nuget-пакеты:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Logic\Logic.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Вроде всё.

Comment: Минус не мой, если что. Я только вопрос поправил (как смог)

Comment: Тоже не мой минус. А здесь точно нужен `FakeItEasy` нугет-пакет? Ну и в тестирующем коде вы объявили `var input      = 5;`, но в метод передали `5`. Получается, объявленная переменная нигде не используется

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Пакет FakeItEasy тут действительно не нужен, это я скопировал с текущего проекта и не почистил перед отправкой. Про input тоже спасибо, не доглядел - поправил ответ.

Comment: Не знаю, за что минус (логика минусующих не всегда очевидна), но если минус за то, что привёл пример не на конкретный пример топикстартера, то могу пояснить, что это сделано намеренно исключительно, чтобы домашку делали самостоятельно -- а автор просил именно наглядный пример для образца, потому я вообще стал отвечать на эту тему.

Comment: На мой взгляд, отдельные проекты - это немного перебор.

Comment: @Qwertiy С одной стороны - да, для простых приложений оверхед (если уже знаешь), с другой стороны именно для тех, кто только осваивает неплохо видеть именно структуру приложения, чтобы не привыкали лапшекод писать.

Comment: @AK, а на фронте принято тесты рядом с тестируемыми файлами класть: `то-же-имя.spec.ts`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мы сейчас не про фронт же говорим? :) Лично мне импонирует [когда](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend/tree/master/src) сборка для тестирования отдельно, чтобы не распухала сборка и не мусорить лишними зависимостями.

Comment: @AK, даЮ согласен, из сборки лучше выкидывать тесты, а на шарпе это затруднительно сделать, если они в одном проекте. Зато когда рядом лежат, довольно удобно.

Comment: спасибо всем,спасибо за обьяснение,препод забыл об этом сказать и все написано в майн .