# Модульное тестирование Windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, тестирование

подскажите есть ли возможность произвести модульное тестирование приложений на основе Windows Forms?
Не нашла в интернете какой - то определенности для себя. Смотрела туториалы по модульному тестированию, как только дошла до вызова класса - встряла. При вызове класса Form, он не отображается, выходит ошибка о том, что данный класс не существует, хотя ссылку на проект в тесте, который необходимо тестировать я добавляла.

Comment: Что имено планируете тестировать? Обычно сначала покрывают тестами сначала бизнес-логику и похоже, что вы её запихали в тот же проект, что и winforms -- а обычно логика отделена от визуального представления. И только когда бизнес-логика оттестирована - начинают тестировать уже сами нажатия на кнопочки, но это не модульное тестирование, это интеграционное.

Comment: `При вызове класса Form` - у вас вся логика расписана в обработчики нажатия на кнопочки. Такой код не годится для модульного тестирования. Вся логика должна быть в классах бизнес-моделей, отдельно от визуального интерфейса программы.

Comment: @Bulson можете скинуть ссылки на примеры, где в приложении вся логика расписана в отдельном классе и потом при нажатии на кнопку данный класс вызывается? в таком случае насколько я понимаю есть возможность модульного тестирования

Comment: Хорошо, напишу примерчик... Ждите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для примера возьмем простейший пример вычисления данных прямоугольника.

Работать будем с уклоном в TDD (Test driven development или "Разработка на основе тестирования").
Создадим решение с проектом, набросаем интерфейс программы.
[image: дизайн окна программы]

1. Добавьте в решение проект библиотеки
   [image: добавление проекта библиотеки]
2. Добавьте в решение тестовый проект xUnit
   [image: добавление тестового проекта]
3. Добавьте ссылки на проект библиотеки в тестовый и WinForms проекты
   [image: добавление ссылок]
4. Создайте в проекте библиотеки класс `MainFormViewModel` для главного окна нашей программы.
5. В проекте тестов переименуйте `UnitTest1` в `MainFormViewModelTests` и добавьте `using Rectangle.Core;`.
   Напишите пару таких тестов

   ```
   public class MainFormViewModelTests
   {
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство ширины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasWidthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Width);
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство длины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasLengthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Length);
    }
   }
   ```

Т.к. в классе не было создано соотв. свойств, то действуйте так
[image: добавление свойства]

6. Теперь запустите тесты
   [image: запуск тестов]

и... тесты не прошли. Это нормально так и должно быть. Исправьте класс так

```
public class MainFormViewModel
{
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}
```

a тесты так

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство ширины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasWidthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        vm.Width = "3";

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Width);
        Assert.Equal("3", vm.Width);
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство длины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasLengthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        vm.Length = "3";

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Length);
        Assert.Equal("3", vm.Length);
    }
```

Добавьте еще два теста

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисляет площадь прямоугольника")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "3";
        vm.Length = "3";

        int area = vm.GetArea();

        Assert.Equal(9, area);
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисляет периметр прямоугольника")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculatePerimeter()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "3";
        vm.Length = "3";

        int perimeter = vm.GetPerimeter();

        Assert.Equal(12, perimeter);
    }
```

и два соответствующих метода в класс въюмодели. Тесты не пройдут.
Подправьте так методы

```
public int GetPerimeter()
    {
        return 12;
    }

    public int GetArea()
    {
        return 9;
    }
```

Убедитесь, что тесты теперь проходят. Далее реализуете методы уже так, чтобы они действительно вычисляли нужные данные и проверяете, что все тесты проходят.
Далее будет по принципу ["Как нарисовать сову"](https://www.yaplakal.com/forum2/topic286982.html)

Вот такие тесты

```
public class MainFormViewModelTests
{
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство ширины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasWidthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        vm.Width = "3";

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Width);
        Assert.Equal("3", vm.Width);
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Въюмодель имеет свойство длины")]
    public void ViewModel_HasLengthProperty()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();

        vm.Length = "3";

        Assert.IsType<string>(vm.Length);
        Assert.Equal("3", vm.Length);
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если высота не число")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfWidthIsNotNumber()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "a";
        vm.Length = "3";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Width", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если высота отрицательное число")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfWidthIsNegativeNumber()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "-3";
        vm.Length = "3";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Width", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если высота равна нулю")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfWidthEqualsZero()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "0";
        vm.Length = "3";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Width", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если высота не число")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfLengthIsNotNumber()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "3";
        vm.Length = "a";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Length", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если длина отрицательное число")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfLengthIsNegativeNumber()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "3";
        vm.Length = "-3";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Length", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Вычисление площади выбрасывает исключение если длина равна нулю")]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea_ThrowsExceptionIfLengthEqualsZero()
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = "3";
        vm.Length = "0";

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>("Length", () => vm.GetArea());
    }

    [Theory(DisplayName = "Вычисляет площадь прямоугольника")]
    [InlineData("3", "3", 9)]
    [InlineData("5", "10", 50)]
    public void ViewModel_CalculateArea(string width, string length, int output)
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = width;
        vm.Length = length;

        int area = vm.GetArea();

        Assert.Equal(output, area);
    }

    [Theory(DisplayName = "Вычисляет периметр прямоугольника")]
    [InlineData("3", "3", 12)]
    [InlineData("5", "10", 30)]
    public void ViewModel_CalculatePerimeter(string width, string length, int output)
    {
        var vm = new MainFormViewModel();
        vm.Width = width;
        vm.Length = length;

        int perimeter = vm.GetPerimeter();

        Assert.Equal(output, perimeter);
    }
}
```

К такому тестируему классу

```
public class MainFormViewModel
{
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }

    public int GetPerimeter()
    {
        int width = GetWidth();
        int length = GetLength();

        return 2 * width + 2 * length;
    }

    public int GetArea()
    {
        int width = GetWidth();
        int length = GetLength();

        return width * length;
    }

    private int GetLength()
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Length, out int length) == false)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Длина должна быть числом.", nameof(Length));
        }
        if (length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Длина должна быть положительным числом.", nameof(Length));
        }

        return length;
    }

    private int GetWidth()
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Width, out int width) == false)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Высота должна быть числом.", nameof(Width));
        }
        if (width <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Высота должна быть положительным числом.", nameof(Width));
        }

        return width;
    }
}
```

7. Теперь используем класс въюмодели так

   ```
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
    private readonly MainFormViewModel _viewModel = new MainFormViewModel();

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //привязки
        _textBoxWidth.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewModel, nameof(MainFormViewModel.Width));
        _textBoxLength.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewModel, nameof(MainFormViewModel.Length));

        _buttonDoCalc.Click += ButtonDoCalc_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonDoCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _labelArea.Text = _viewModel.GetArea().ToString();
            _labelPerimeter.Text = _viewModel.GetPerimeter().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка");
        }
    }
    }
   ```

Всё! Ссылка на этот пример [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/TDDdemo).

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Обычно новички в программировании слабо различают такую вещь, как слои приложения и часто смешивают воедино бизнес-логику и визуальное представление. Такой код сложнее и в поддержке, рефакторинге и в тестировании.

Типичный пример - в обработчик клика на кнопку помещают логику (открывают соединение с FTP-сервером, производят сложные расчёты и т.п.), можете просто [посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bwinforms%5D+button1_Click) сами.

На примере приложения-калькулятора: вы можете нафигачить код прямо в своё winforms-приложение, но если вы выделите класс калькулятора без привязки ко всем этим object sender, EventArgs e то ваш код можно будет весьма просто тестировать, а потом этот протестированный класс калькулятора многократно использовать - хоть в консольном приложении, хоть в winforms, хоть в WPF или веб-приложении asp.net mvc.

А потому, пока у вас вообще нет никаких тестов -- начните с простых модульных тестов без всякой привязки к (интеграционному) тестированию UI-интерфейса winforms. А для этого вам нужно будет отделить логику от представления.

Кратко и сжато как тестировать код есть например здесь: [Как писать юнит тесты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190974/213987)

Можете в отдельные проекты не выносить, но убрать зависимость от классов winforms — важно.