# Как создать правильно модульное тестирование на пустое значение в TextBox и PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создал библиотеку, и прописал для неё логику. Вызываю эту библиотеку в самом проекте, и через приложение она нормально отрабатывается.

Но мне ещё надо сделать проверку через Модульное тестирование. Но что то не понимаю как составить правильно.

Вот сома библиотека

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот юнит тест[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Не надо размещать код в виде картинок. 2) Вам надо отвязать логику проверки пароля от работы с UI. И тогда можно будет провести тестирование.

Comment: Понял, код не буду картинками размещать.

На счёт UI - не понял. Что это ?

Comment: UI - user interface (пользовательский интерфейс программы.)

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222500/222542

Answer (score 1):

> Юнит тест

```
[TestClass]
public class ChekingBox
{

        [TestMethod]
        public void NullLogPas()
        {
            var nullLogPas = "Вы не ввели логин и пароль";
            TextBox logBox = null;

            PasswordBox pasBox = null;


           var sms =   CheckingBox.LoginPassword(logBox, pasBox);

            Assert.AreEqual(nullLogPas, sms);
        }
    }
```

```
public class CheckingBox
{
    public static string LoginPassword(TextBox textBox, PasswordBox passwordBox)
    {
        var sms = "";
        if (textBox.Text.Length == 0  && passwordBox.Password.Length == 0)
        {
          sms = Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show("Вы не ввели логин и пароль", "Ошибка!",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error));
        }
       else if (textBox.Text.Length != 0 && passwordBox.Password.Length == 0)
       {
          sms =Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show("Вы не ввели  пароль", "Ошибка!",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error));
       }
       else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0 && passwordBox.Password.Length != 0)
       {
          sms =Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show("Вы не ввели логин", "Ошибка!",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error));
       }

        return sms;
    }
}
```